# Sqlite.swift live search

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I want to do a live search on the DB.

Lets say I want to search by companies and I have the following info on a column named companies.

- Facebook
- FastCompany
- Facebook
- Google
- Microsoft

I have a textfield that has calls a function on editchanged.

```
   @IBAction func searching(sender: AnyObject) {
        tempstring = "%"+searchBar.text+"%"
        println(tempstring)

         user = user.select(name)
            .filter(like(tempstring, name))
            .limit(30, offset: 0)
        collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

It kind of works, if I start typing "**fa**"
It will show (**Facebook, Facebook and FastCompany**)

If I continue typing "**fac**" it will show (**Facebook, Facebook**)

But when I delete the last character "**c**"  from the searchbox (leaving it in "fa" again) then the query displays nothing.

Any ideas on how I can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is coming from over writing the `user` object with each search. This is fine as long as you only move forward, but when you go backwards like you did, the query messes up.

Instead, try adding a `currentQuery` property to your view controller with the collection view in it and set it to your `user.select` statement.

```
currentQuery = user.select(name)
        .filter(like(tempstring, name))
        .limit(30, offset: 0)
```

Then use the `currentQuery` object to display the results instead. This way, no matter what you're searching, it will match everything.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot.